# como detectar cuando regreso a una pagina con java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema con un reporte en el cual incluyo fechas que se cargan a unos controles con una función javascript esta misma la llamo en  mi document.ready para que me ponga fechas del dia de hoy y luego se ejectuta mi bisqueda segun esas fechas hasta ahi todo bien,mi problema llega cuando selecciono ciertas fechas y hago mi busqueda tengo la opcion de ir a otra pagina a ver los detalles de algun registro mi busqueda pero al momento de dare back me vuelve a ejecutar la funcion java script de las fechas y me quita las que seleccione con anterioridad, saben si hay algun metodo que me ayude a detectar cuando estoy dandole back o forward a la pagina y poder mantener los datos?

Comment: estas usando algún login o haces uso de una master page?

Answer (score 1):

intenta guardarlos en el `localStorage` con esto lo guardas localmente aunque cambies de pagina o cierres el navegador

```
localStorage.setItem("date1", "29/01/18");

var mydate= localStorage.getItem("date1");
```

Cuando ya no utilices la variable eliminala con `localStorage.removeItem("date1");`